# sqlldr: Getting 'ORA-19032: Expected XML tag, got no content' for null values

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I'm trying to load a table with oracle sqlldr but get `ORA-19032: Expected XML tag, got no content` on (allowed!) null fields.

If the table is populated by inserts, or the column is updated to null, everthing is fine. But loading via `sqlldr` doesn't work.

Loader call:

```
sqlldr $DBCS control=$TABLE.ctl data=$TABLE.csv bad=$LOGDIR/$TABLE.bad log=$LOGDIR/$TABLE.log rows=10000 bindsize=20000000 readsize=20000000 silent=header,feedback
```

CTL-File:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE MY_TABLE.csv "STR '|\n'"
INTO TABLE MY_TABLE APPEND
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
  "NORMAL_COLUMN1" CHAR(40)
, "NORMAL_COLUMN2" CHAR(250)
, "NORMAL_COLUMN3" CHAR(250)
, "XML_COLUMN" CHAR(16000)
)
```

Table Definition:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE
(
  NORMAL_COLUMN1        NUMBER(14) not null,
  NORMAL_COLUMN2        VARCHAR2(250) not null,
  NORMAL_COLUMN3        VARCHAR2(250),
  XML_COLUMN            SYS.XMLTYPE    
);
```

csv line - not working:

```
21001;"lulul";"lalal";|
```

csv line - working:

```
21001;"lulul";;"<a>ala</a>"|
```

*Note*: In general, i'd create "correct" datatypes for the "normal columns", but the ctl-file is created by an unload-script...and it works ;)

**Important**: It works for non-null values for the xml column.

I hope there is a way to modify the corresponding line in the ctl-File, but i didn't find a solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be that at some point within that loader execution something similar to the following is occurring where the `NULL` value is being passed as a parameter to the `XmlType(value)` constructor or the `createXML(value)` function:

```
select XmlType('') as xml_value from dual;
```

I have tried a few ways to work around it with no success. I can continue to research it when I have more time, but I wanted to at least post this as an explanation. You could (hackily) work around this by doing something like:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE MY_TABLE.csv "STR '|\n'"
INTO TABLE MY_TABLE APPEND
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
  "NORMAL_COLUMN1" CHAR(40)
, "NORMAL_COLUMN2" CHAR(250)
, "NORMAL_COLUMN3" CHAR(250)
, "Nvl(XML_COLUMN, '<empty />')" CHAR(16000)
)
```

Not the ideal solution, but it should get you moving forward. Let me know if you end up just going this route, otherwise I will see if I can find something better.

Comment: Thank you, i even thought about that solution, but a the moment i got an constraint that `NORMAL_COLUMN3 XOR XML_COLUMN` is `NULL` so I'd need a workaround after the workaround, if I'd go that way :(

Comment: @evilive You can put a `BEFORE` row trigger on that table that checks the incoming value and if it is equal to '<empty />' then set it to null. That should do the trick.

Comment: @gimley: Ok thank you again, but that's all getting too dirty ;) I choosed the XML-datatype to be constistent to a "close" other table, and because it would be better if it would work (XPATH in manual queries, no invalid XML-structures possible etc.). But as the application works with varchar2 as well, I now just switched to that and all our "standard processes" can work as ever. I'll accept your answer anyway, because the ORA-19032 would be gone ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use nval function with XMLTYPE to provide dummy xml in case of null value.

EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(nvl(XML_COLUMN, '1')), '/XPATh/')